# Compare date in MySQL database from a Perl script

Tags: mysql, perl

I've a Perl script with a MySQL query as below

```
my $date         = strftime "%Y-%m-%d", localtime;

my $db_passwdcol = "password";
my $db_table     = "users";
my $db_usercol   = "username";
my $db_cond      = "expire_date";

my $sql_query    = "SELECT $db_passwdcol FROM $db_table WHERE $db_usercol = ?" . ($db_cond gt $date ? ");
```

What I want to do is compare current with the expired date ones using an SQL query. I've tried many variations but hopeless.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You should probably get the current time in your SQL query instead of using Perl's `localtime`. That way, you're always using your database server's timezone and not trying to compare apples to oranges.

Comment: That code doesn't make much sense and has imbalanced double quotes. What did you really mean?

Answer (score 1):

To change sql query string as below that worked for me;

```
 $sql_query = "SELECT $db_passwdcol FROM $db_table WHERE $db_usercol = ? AND $db_cond > NOW()";
```

Best,